# If custom category search then page 2 not found

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm using a custom post type named fotograf. If it shows all photos in archive page, no problem. It finds photos in every page. But if I'm search a custom category in fotograf custom post type, then nothing found if paged>=2. Just finds the page 1.

You can test it in my web site. http://www.onurunwebsitesi.com

Click to Tümünü Göster (Show All), and click Diğer (Other) category and click pagination links at bottom. 2nd page and others not found.

My code:

archive-fotograf.php

```
<?php /** * Displays the Pagination in Custom loop * */?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php 
$temp = $wp_query; //save old query
$wp_query= null; //clear $wp_query
$aranan= $_GET['s']; 
$kategorim = intval($_GET['cat']);
$myterm = get_term( $kategorim, 'fgaleri' ); 
$myslug = $myterm->slug; ?>
<div id="content">
<?php 
$rakam= 0;
//The query
$wp_query = new WP_Query();

// HERE IS MY WP_QUERY. WHERE IS MY FAULT? IF CUSTOM CATEGORY SEARCH, THEN PAGE 2 NOT FOUND. PLEASE, HELP ME. THANKS IN ADVANCE. 

$wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' =>'fotograf', 's' => $aranan, 'paged' => $paged, 'taxonomy' => 'fgaleri', 'fgaleri' => $myslug ) );
//The loop
?>
<div id="FGaleri_2"><div id="FGaleri_Ic"><div id="FGaleriBaslik">Fotoğraf Galerisi 
<form action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>" id="searchformfoto" method="get" name="searchform">
<?php $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'fgaleri', 'show_option_none' => 'Kategori Seç ve Ara', 'hierarchical' => 1 ); wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
<div id="aramabolumufoto">
<input name="s" id="sfoto" type="text" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="fotograf" />
<input id="searchsubmitfoto" type="submit" value="Ara"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="FGaleri_Ic_2"><?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post(); $rakam++; ?>
<div class="FGaleriItem2" style="<?php if ($rakam % 5 == 0 ) { ?>margin-right: 0px;<?php } ?>">
<?php
$termargs=array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'desc');
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'fgaleri', $termargs );
$t = count($terms);
if ($t>0) { ?>
<div class="fkategori">
<?php 
$c = 0;
foreach($terms as $term) {
$c++;
if ($c==$t) 
{ 
echo '<a class="foto_kategori" href="'. home_url() . '/?cat=' . $term->term_id . '&post_type=fotograf&fgaleri=' . $term->slug . '" title="' . $term->name . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> ';
}
} ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="ResimUst">
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
$url2 = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/timthumb.php?src=" . $url . "&amp;w=100&amp;h=100&amp;zc=1"; ?>
<img src="<?php if(get_option('of_timthumb')=="true") { echo $url2; } else { echo $url; } ?>" alt="" title="" width="100" height="100" />
</a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="ResimAlt">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {     
wp_pagenavi(); //function call for plugin pagination( wp pagenavi plugin)
}else{ ?>     
<div id="navigasyon">
<span class="previous-entries">
<?php next_posts_link('« Daha Eski Fotoğraflar'); ?></span>
<span class="next-entries"><?php previous_posts_link('Daha Yeni Fotoğraflar »'); ?    ></span>
</div><?php } //endif
?><?php
$wp_query = null; //Reset the normal query
$wp_query = $temp; //Restore the query
?>
</div><?php get_sidebar(); ?></div><?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query you pass `'paged' => $paged`, but you never assign a value to `$paged`, so you are always seeing the first page of results. try defining it first:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' =>'fotograf', 's' => $aranan, 'paged' => $paged, 'taxonomy' => 'fgaleri', 'fgaleri' => $myslug ) );
```

Comment: Nothing changed, mate...

Comment: Do **NOT** post authentication information for your website or server in a public forum.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into your code and figured that you have pretty much messed up the code. I have made some changes in your code and now the pagination seems to work fine.
I have commented out some action hooks in your functions.php and some lines in archive-fotograf.php. You may uncomment that and look out what was creating the problems

Comment: Hi. What you did changed? Because I thought my codes doesn't work and I uploaded my theme again. :( Your changes is lost. :( Please, write here what you did. I'm waiting. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I just viewed your website and it seems pagination is working fine, it is showing different posts in each pagination.

Comment: Yes, pagination works in all photos list. but click to Diğer (other) category, and you can see pagination at bottom. And it's still not working.

Comment: oh yep i didn't see that, let me see if i can fix that

Comment: You know my username and password. 

Open this link: http://www.onurunwebsitesi.com/?cat=494&post_type=fotograf&fgaleri=diger&paged=2

It is not working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually page 2 seems to redirect to index.php thats why its showing no posts. I think you should be using taxonomy.php to show posts under your custom category. All the custom caterories are your taxonomy term. They will be searching the taxonomy.php file and if not found falls back to archive and if not found archive falls back to index. I think the same is happening with your code. Try to look template hierarchy and create a taxonomy.php file which will be almost similar to your custom post type file.

Comment: I created taxonomy.php . Now, what should I write to taxonomy.php ? I'm so sorry, because my English is not good as you. If you write here what I must to do, I will be happy. Thanks in advance.